# Set label and id on BPMN lane programmatically

Tags: javascript, bpmn, bpmn-js, bpmn-moddle

How can I change the label/name and id of a lane in `bpmn-js` or `bpmn-moddle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it just on the business object of the lane.

```js
import { getBusinessObject } from 'bpmn-js/lib/util/ModelUtil';

const bo = getBusinessObject(laneElement);
bo.id = 'someId';
bo.name = 'Some Name';
```